# How long will it take for google to release a deleted account username

Tags: google, email-accounts

I had been using a google account long back. I am unable to access it now. Either me or google had deleted the account. How long will google take to release the username of the deleted account to use it again?

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it is about user names for Google accounts and not about running your own website.

Comment: Moderators can move it to the respective category instead of closing it.

Comment: I'd move it to some other site, but I don't know where it would be on-topic.

Answer (score 2):

### Accounts Are Never Released

According to [Google](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/gILW5x3JeG0), they do not release them.

> For a limted time (around a month), you can restore your deleted
>   [account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6236295):
>
> But if it was a long time ago, unfortunately you cannot. Moreover,
>   Google does not allow the re-use (re-registration) of long time
>   deleted accounts [either](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/66278):    I know, I have lost an account this
>   way and have never been able to reuse it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hotmail got hardly abused because was following this tactic, I guess Google learned from those mistakes and is not allowing people to re-use a deleted e-mail.